# Scanning a file as a string

Tags: ocaml

I have a built a function which takes as input a string and output a string.
Let's call it `f`.
I would like to scan the string into a file `input.txt` and apply my function on this string and write it on another file `output.txt`.

Other questions: If the file is too big, maybe the scanning is impossible. Thus I have a function `f_line`, and I would like to scan one by one each line of `input.txt` and apply this function to this line, and write each output in the file in the file `output.txt`.
How can I do that?

Comment: Check [Real World OCaml](https://dev.realworldocaml.org/imperative-programming.html#file-io)

Comment: It doesn't help me (In_channel doesn't work on my computer)

Comment: Seems to me you're asking the wrong question then, if your computer can't do basic I/O.

Comment: I've finally made it with open_in.

Comment: You can always post the trouble you face with respect to tools you are using for OCaml related stuff. However, simply saying `doesn't work` isn't that helpful for us.

Comment: It returns "unbbound constructor In_channel"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found an easy solution with the following code :

```ml
let transform_files_by_line 
    (f_line : string -> string) 
    (in_filename : string) 
    (out_filename : string) =
  let input_chan = open_in in_filename 
  and output_chan = open_out out_filename
  in
  let rec transform_rec () =
    let str = input_line input_chan in
    output_string output_chan (f_line str);
    transform_rec ();
  in
  try 
    transform_rec () 
  with
    End_of_file -> (
      close_in input_chan;
      close_out output_chan;
    );;
```

Comment: Now can you make this more generically useful by wrapping it up in a function? Something like `transform_files_by_line f in_filename out_filename`.

Comment: Is it better like this?

Comment: A few bits of feedback. Style: I would indent the contents of the function. Functionality: why have you hard-coded in `1067`? Can you achieve this with recursion rather than an imperative loop?

Comment: It 's because I don't know how to manage the initial case (when the file is empty).

Comment: Check the documentation [here](https://ocaml.org/api/Stdlib.html#2_Generalinputfunctions). You'll see that Ocaml raises an `End_of_file` exception in this situation. You just need to handle this exception.

Comment: Thank, I've modified the code. But I don't know how to indent on SE.

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 2):

You basically want to *map* a file with your function to another file, much like you map lists, e.g.,

```
# List.map String.uppercase_ascii ["hello"; "world"];;
- : string list = ["HELLO"; "WORLD"]
```

In OCaml, files are read and written via an abstraction called a channel. Channels have directions, i.e., input channels are distinguished from the output channels. To open an input channel use the `open_in` function, to close it, use `close_in`. The corresponding functions for the output channels have the `_out` prefix.

To map two channels line by line, we need to read a line from one channel, apply our transformation `f` to each line and write to the output channel, until the first channel raises the `End_of_file` exception that indicates that there is no more data, e.g.,

```
let rec map_channels input output f =
  match f (input_line input) with
  | exception End_of_file -> flush output
  | r ->
    output_string output r;
    output_char output '\n';
    map_channels input output f
```

Now we can use this function to write a function that takes filenames, instead of channels, e.g.,

```
let map_files input output f =
  if input = output
  then invalid_arg "the input and output files must differ";
  let input = open_in input in
  let output = open_out output in
  map_channels input output f;
  close_in input;
  close_out output
```

Notice, that we are checking that input and output files are different to prevent mapping the file to itself, which might end up in an infinite loop and may corrupt files.

Comment: Are you sure the "output_char output '\n';" is needed?

Comment: flushing the output seems unnecessary

Comment: (this is just an example, but "input = output" doesn't guard against filesystem aliases)

Comment: Yes, the `input_line` function reads until the end of the line and discards the end-of-line character. @coredump flushing output is necessary, otherwise, the data will be stuck in the buffer of the channel. Yes, it is closed later by the map_files function, but `map_channels` shall be self-contained as well and fulfill its contracts. Concerning the check, yes it is not sufficient, but good enough for the example.

Comment: I wouldn't include flushing the output in the contract of that function, considering the function doesn't create/own the channels; I wouldn't like a library function to make intermediate calls to flush when e.g. replicating "cat" with `map_channels i o Fun.id` for a list of input channels i

Comment: Well, `cat` flushes after each line, we flush after each file (or when the buffer is overflowed). But again, for didactic purposes, it is important to show that you have to flush and that the concept of flush at all exists. That was my main motivation. Despite that I still believe that map_channels shall flush the output (speaking of libraries, I don't think it is a good library function at all).

Comment: @ivg I can't find a cat that calls fflush(3) (eg in https://github.com/pete/cats), in fact attaching a breakpoint for fflush under gdb for my local copy of cat only breaks execution when closing the output file (for one or more inputs)

Comment: Okay, cat is not line-buffered. Doesn't really change anything. To my taste this function shall flush, at least for testing it. Next, it is important for people to learn how channels are buffered and that they should be flushed for the results to come. Finally, it is not worthwhile the discussion at all, we already lost too much time on such a nuisance that is totally irrelevant to the topic.